# Warning when using - binary operator in C++ to take away int from variable. What is the cause?

Tags: c++, arithmetic-expressions

I have a function which has an integer as a formal parameter:

```
string function1(int hundreds)
{
// some code
else if (hundreds > 9)
{ 
    hundreds - 5;
}
```

When I compile this code, I get a warning message located at the binary minus operator saying 'expression result unused'. What causes this warning message to be thrown?

My guess is that it is not good practice to minus a constant integer, and instead, I should have defined a variable of type `const int` which has a value of `5` and taken this away from `hundreds` instead. i.e instead of `hundreds - 5` I should have used:

```
const int DEDUCTION = 5;
//code up to the following statement
hundreds - DEDUCTION;
```

Comment: you get "expression result is unused" because the result of hundreds - 5 is not being used.  what are you trying to do?  hundreds = hundreds - 5; (or equivalently hundreds -= 5;)

Comment: `hundreds - 5;` This doesn't do anything - this statement has no side effects. Did you mean `hundreds -= 5;`?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That is exactly what I meant :) Sorry, its been a long day. I should remove this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either assign the result to another variable or assign it back as `hundreds -= 5;`. Otherwise the result is simply dropped.

Answer (score 1):

Because `hundreds - 5` doesn't do anything. It's like writing `if ( hundreds > 9 ) { 1; }`.

Answer (score 0):

Because a result of arithmetic subtraction is not used, you've got the appropriate warning.
You assumption concerning replacement of number 5 by const int is not right, because that doesn't remove the reason of the warning.

Comment: "Binary operator" means operator that takes two arguments; this is binary minus and the arguments are `hundreds` and `5`.